# How to preserve data in DataGridView after unbinding it?

Tags: c#, datagridview, binding, datasource, unbind

I need to unbind the datasource from datagridview in order to add rows programmatically, but i'm unable to keep the data preserved in the datagridview after unbinding it. any solution? here is the code:

```
try
{
   XmlReader xmlFile = XmlReader.Create(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "data.xml", new XmlReaderSettings());
   ds.ReadXml(xmlFile);
   dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
   dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
   dataGridView1.Refresh();
   dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;

   //  dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false; 
   dataGridView1.DataSource = null;

   // dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Eroor! "+ ex);
}
```

Comment: Why do you have to unbind it? Can't you add some row programmatically in your data source? Otherwise you could create a DataSet as a property and import the data you read from the Xml to this DataSet. Then point your DS to this DataSet.

Comment: I can't add row programmatically when the datagrid is in-bound. i get this exception error when i try to do it..  “Rows cannot be programatically added to datagridview's row collection when the control is data-bound”

Comment: If you have new data that correctly maps the same as your previous data, then just add it to the `DataSource` instead of to the `DataGridView`.

Comment: @OhBeWise Oh, that's right! feel stupid for not thinking about. it works fine, thanks!